# Why click in div don't work in phantomJS?

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I'm trying to click in a div that should open a new window. When using Chrome it work fine:
`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="situacaoSenha"]/div/div').click()`
But when I change to PhantomJS it don't work. I viryify and the new window didn't open.
`print(driver.window_handles)`

Comment: Can you elaborate bit more, what are you trying to achieve, what did you already try?

Comment: I'm trying to click in a div that open a new window. I've try driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="situacaoSenha"]/div/div').click()

Comment: Are you aware of this: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/c5e4a585f1e3c4b3468ec93ab50d3668d47aef1b#diff-16fa7e439f764ef9668676a211769d37R8